# Building boost examples in linux

Tags: python, c++, linux, boost, boost-python

I've installed all the boost and boost-related packages from synaptic manager.  If I ran "bjam" from the  directory getting error :

```
error: Unable to load Jamfile.
error: Could not find a Jamfile in directory '/usr/share/boost- build/kernel'.
error: Attempted to find it with pattern '[Bb]uild.jam [Jj]amfile.v2 [Jj]amfile [Jj]amfile.jam'.
error: Please consult the documentation at 'http://www.boost.org'.
```